# Выравнивание по левому краю содержимого Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Как выровнять `ImageView` по левому краю до самого конца, чтобы не было отступа как на скриншоте ниже?

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarDebug"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgToolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/photo" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDebug"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Что-то я заметил, что довольно часто по этому поводу задают вопросы, почему-то всем не нравится выравнивание

Comment: Посмотрите исходники ToolBar, скорее всего там стоит отступ по дефолту, тогда не судьба

Answer (score 4):

Многие пытаются избавиться от этого отступа, выставляя нулевой PaddingLeft, что в корне неверно, ибо причина отступа - `android:contentInsetStart` (`contentInsetLeft` для версий постарше). Код стиля ниже определен для `<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/rollserv_toolbar</item>` кастомной темы.

```
    <style name="rollserv_toolbar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/rollserv_orange</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="contentInsetStart">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:logo">@drawable/app_logo</item>
    </style>
```

Также есть возможность определить/получить это свойство программно, подробнее в документации к функциям `setContentInsetsRelative(int, int) setContentInsetsAbsolute(int, int) getContentInsetStart() getContentInsetEnd() getContentInsetRight()`

[Документация toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

Comment: Ссылка-то битая...

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 2):

Хотя вопрос уже задан давно, но возможно кому-то пригодится. 
Как ответил выше Dmitry Nevzorov, для того, чтобы убрать в toolbar отступ слева (который по умолчанию 16dp), нужно использовать свойство `contentInsetStart` или для старых устройств `contentInsetLeft`. Это можно сделать так - в layout-файл тулбара добавьте строки:

```
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
```

Подробнее [ответ дан тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, нужно выставить `layout_gravity="left"` или `gravity="left"`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?